# How to forward error_log and access_log to both stderr and stdout and files

Tags: docker, nginx

By default, nginx's `access.log` and `error.log` are redirected to `stderr` and `stdout`.

What I want is:

When I exec into the container and run `tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`, I would be able to see the logs. And also when I run `docker logs nginx`, I can see the logs.

I just know if I want to see the logs in the file, I should run `rm /var/log/nginx/* && nginx -s reload`, and if I do nothing, logs are available via `docker logs nginx`.

But how to have both at the same time?

Comment: Why do you need to exec into the container at all?  I wouldn't try to run `nginx reload` like you show; just delete and recreate the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, for some reasons I need to have both of them at the same time. I need my developer to use API to get logs https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerLogs. There are multiple devs and I want they can be able to see the logs of their own service. Also me as an Op team member I need to separate both error and access log files for myself